# Is it possible to set up a second monitor/display that doesn't change when switching desktop on your main with unity's desktop wall?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to set up a second monitor/display that doesn't change when switching desktop on your main with unity's desktop wall? This is possible with the Gnome3-desktop, but I can't switch over to that interface.

Why would I want one display to remain static? Its nice to always have a chat window or video stream playing whilst you are actually working on the other monitor.

Please let me know any workarounds/ideas/solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I know of the possibility to have a window present in whichever workspace you are: right-click on the title bar of any window and select **Always in the visible workspace**.

[image: window menu always on visible workspace]

<sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version</sup>

Now, this is not a solution to your question, but I think it can work until one is proposed.